# Find all sets of orthogonal vectors from a given vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, orthogonality

I am on a lookout for a method to obtain all possible sets of orthogonal vectors from some known vector space where the field is $F_2$,i.e. binary. Does there exist any such method. I tried looking up the net but in vain. I know that one of the set can be obtained by considering the basis of the space and then using Gram Schimdt orthogonalization. But is there any method to obtain all the sets?

Comment: Do you like to provide a concrete example of a vector space that interests you?

Comment: Gram Schmidt orthogonalization doesn't work over $\Bbb{F}_2$, because it may lead you to divide by zero.

Comment: The question is IMHO a bit strange because there are vector spaces $V$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$ such that all the vectors of $V$ are orthogonal to all the vectors of $V$ (including themselves). In coding theory these are called self-orthogonal codes. A common example is the subspace $V$ of $\Bbb{F}_2^8$ spanned by $11110000$
$11001100$, $10101010$ and $11111111$. The space is 4-dimensional and equal to its dual, in other words $$V=V^\perp=\{\vec{y}\in\Bbb{F}_2^8\mid (\vec{y},\vec{x})=0\ \text{for all $\vec{x}\in V$}\}.$$ In such a space all its subsets are orthogonal.